# Search words in file and print their position in bytes?

Tags: c, file, nlp

Im reaching out to you with a question I have for a school assignment. As the programming-course is being entirely held at distance and I have no peers or teachers to ask for help: SO is my lifeline.

**Challenge: Write a program which scans an arbitrary file for a word (which the user specifies) and determine if it occurs in the file. If the word is found in the file, the program should also specify the number of bytes in the file where the word was found. Furthermore, if the word is found more than once, all locations should be presented.**

```
Example of output: 
Your word was found 3 time(s):
The first time X bytes into the file.
The second time Y bytes into the file.
The third time Z bytes into the file.
```

How can this be solved?

I am sure you are curious of what I have got so far...

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>


int main(int argc, char*argv[])
{
   int pos, num = 0;
   char word[35]; //deciding a word is not longer than 35 bytes
   char *string;
   
   FILE *fptr = fopen("test.txt", "r");  //I have created a text test-text-file which I am opening
   if (fptr == NULL)
   {
   printf("Error file missing");
   exit (-1);
   }


   printf("\nInsert a word to look for in the file\n");
   scanf("%s", word);
   printf("\nOkay the word to look for is: %s\n", word);
 
   while(!feof(fptr))  //using feof to find the end of file
   {
   fscanf(fptr, "%s", string);
   if(!strcmp(string,word))//compare the string with word
   num++;        //Incrementing if the word was found, thereby stating how many times the word was found
   }

  printf("The word %s was found %d times\n", word, num);
```

OK. So far so good. Now I am lost, what I want is a function to return how many bytes into the file that the word(s) were found (if they are found). I really don't know how. I understand that fseek could probably be a good idea, and some sort of loop to print the positions, but I am unsure of how to use it for this purpose.

ALL your help is much appreciated Stack Over-flowers. Go hard on me!

Answer (score 1):

**Each character has 1 byte.** Thus, what you have to do basically is count how many characters there are in the file, and at which character your word starts.

---

Bear in mind that there are numerous ways to do this. Since you mentioned the use of fseek and ftell, I will provide a simple explanation using ftell.

Basically, ftell tells you the current position of the pointer, in bytes. Hence, after you've identified a word, do:

```
position = ftell(fptr);
```

This will get you the current position of your file pointer, i.e, right *after* reading the selected word. Thus you have to subtract the length of your word from that. (I.e, if the first world in the file is "Hello", the ftell will return 5, since immediately after reading the word the pointer stops at 5.
Since you are using string.h, obtaining the length of the string is straightforward.

Comment: I understand how to calculate the characters of a file using fseek and ftell. But how does one count where a found word starts? I think I need more clues...

Comment: I will edit my answer in a way where you can use these two functions, then.

Comment: Still have not solved it @Mölp. Do you think I could go for a while loop like this: `while(!feof(in_file)) {
 fscanf(in_file, "%s", string); 
 if(!strcmp(string,word))//if match found, tell the position of the word
 pos = ftell(in_file);
 printf("The word was found %d bytes into the file\n", (pos-i));  //i is the lenght of the word

Comment: I can't see the difference between what you wrote and what is written in my answer.

Comment: No exactly, see my answer and you will understand. Thanks for your kind and awesome help.

Comment: I don't have enough reputation to comment on your answer. But in short, you don't need two while loops, one will suffice. In fact, two while loops won't work, because after you finish executing the first one, the file pointer is already at the end of the file. In the first loop, inside the if statement (that is, once you've found the word), you call fseek.

Comment: Also, don't forget that if you want more than one line of code inside an if statement you need to use curly braces.

Answer (score 0):

I have a code that almost does the trick. I have followed the suggestion by @Mölp. However, since I am such a rookie, I quite cannot get it right. The problem is that my code does not print the position of the word even though it is found in the file. Thus, the problem lies within the second while-loop. I cannot for the world understand why this would not work?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <utility.h>


int main(int argc, char*argv[])
{
    int pos, i, num = 0;
    char word[35];
    char string[1000];
    
    printf("This program will open an arbitrary text file and search for a specific word within that file\n");
    FILE *in_file = fopen("test.txt", "r");
    
    if (in_file == NULL)
    {
        printf("Error file missing"); 
        exit (-1);
    }
    else {printf("\nFile opened successfully\n");
    }
    
    printf("\nInsert a word to look for in the file:\n"); 
    scanf("%s", word);
    printf("\nOkay the word to search for is: '%s' and it is %d letters long.\n", word, strlen(word));
 
    while(!feof(in_file))
    {
        fscanf(in_file, "%s",string); 
        if(!strcmp(string,word))//if match found increment num
            num++;
    }
    
    while(!feof(in_file))
    {
        fscanf(in_file, "%s", string); 
        if(!strcmp(string,word))//if match found, tell the position of the word
            pos = ftell(in_file);
            printf("The word was found %d bytes into the file\n", (pos-i)); //print the position of the word in the file by removing num of letters in the word
    }
    
    printf("\nThe word '%s' was found '%d' times\n", word, num); 
    
    while(!KeyHit()); 
    return 0; 
}
´´´
```